# How to find the second quantized form of Hamiltonian for particle in a box?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, variational-principle, quantum-computer, second-quantization

A single particle Hamiltonian can be written in the second quantized form as follows:
$$F_{1}= \sum f_i(r_i,p_i)$$
$$F_1=\sum(l|f_i|l')a_{l}^{\dagger}a_l$$
When we use this for the hamiltonian of a particle in a box,
$$ H=-\frac{h^2}{2m} d^2/dx^2$$
We get,
$$H=\sum l^2\pi^2h^2a_{l}^{\dagger}a_l/2ma^2$$
Would this hamiltonian correspond to particle in a box problem?

When I minimize the energy of this Hamiltonian using VQE after applying J-W Transformation i get the minimum eigen value as zero instead of expected value of $\pi^2h^2/2ma^2$ which is roughly equal to 4.93 for our case of h=a=m=1.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Hamiltonian
$$H=\sum_{l=1}^\infty \frac{l^2\pi^2h^2}{2ma^2}a_l^{\dagger}a_l$$
(with $a_l^\dagger$ and $a_l$ being the creation and annihilation operators)
does not just describe a *single* particle in a box.

Instead it describes *any number* of particles in a box.
This includes superpositional states with a mixture
of different numbers of particles.

For example:

- $|\psi\rangle = |0\rangle$ is the state with no particle at all
  (the so-called vacuum state, not a single-particle-state with $l=0$).
  Its energy is $E=0$.
- $|\psi\rangle = a_3^\dagger|0\rangle$ is a state
  with a single particle (with $l=3$).
  Its energy is $E=\frac{3^2\pi^2 h^2}{2ma^2}$.
- $|\psi\rangle = a_3^\dagger a_5^\dagger|0\rangle$ is a state
  with a two particles (one with $l=3$, another with $l=5$).
  It energy is $E=\frac{3^2\pi^2 h^2}{2ma^2}+\frac{5^2\pi^2 h^2}{2ma^2}$.

Comment: So if i set l=1 in the hamiltonian, i'd get just one term $$ca_1^{\dagger}a_1$$, then when i apply j-w transformation i'd get the one qubit hamiltonian c'(I-Z) which is $$\matrix{0 0\\0 2}$$, which gives zero as minimum eigenvalue which is absurd. What am i doing wrong here?